# Skipping through numbers of a loop in java in an arraylist

Tags: java

Hello im trying to loop through an array list and whichever number doesnt have a corresponding Object gets a seperate text output but I get to 8 and it just repeats once it gets to the else statement.

i = 8 output : "radio 8 fbf"
i = 9+ output : //No GBT with LocID 9    This repeats even though there are radios 10-30

```
 for(int i = 0; i < alInfo.size(); i++) 
         {   
             if(alInfo.get(i).LocId == i + 1 )
             {
                 out.println((alInfo.get(i).codeLine));
             }
            else
             {
                 //No GBT with LocID 9
                 out.println("//No GBT with LocID " + (i + 1));
                 
             }
         }
```

Comment: It seems unusual to expect a `LocID` to match an  `i + 1` value.  Perhaps `alInfo` is not sorted by `LocID` or there are gaps in `LocID` values.

Comment: There are gaps. When a gap comes up I want it to output there is nothing at the number and move to the next

Comment: well, every subsequent iteration would likely also be a gap